# icons are the same

Tags: visual-studio-code

All my icons are the same， when i use the `vscode` to create anything all language icons are the same

[image]

[image]

Uninstalling it, reinstalling it is the same.

Comment: Before, if it was C language, the icon would be "C", and if it was PHP, the icon would be an elephant. I could quickly tell which language it was. Now, it's difficult for me to quickly determine it

Comment: see: [File and Folder Icons in VS Code!](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes). you need to change the 'File Icon Theme' to the desired value.

Comment: @Luuk their screenshots look to be of their file explorer and desktop- i.e. not within VS Code- in which case your comment is not applicable here.

Comment: What operating system are you on (and what desktop environment is this if this is Linux)? Please also describe where exactly you are taking these screenshots from. Also, does this happen for all files with those extensions and not just the ones that you edited with VS Code? Or only those that you edited with VS Code?